# 2 fields in thinking_sphinx search

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have two fields that I am passing into thinking_sphinx, one is a dropdown, the other a free text.

```
<%= select :search, params[:search], Category.joins(:posts).select('distinct           categories.*').collect {|category| [ category.categoryname,category.categoryname ]}, :include_blank => 'Select a category...' %>

<%= text_field_tag :resume, params[:resume] %>
```

Its working with just the dropdown, but my syntax seems to be wrong to get the 2nd one to work.

```
    @posts = Post.search :conditions=>{:search=>params[:search]},{:resume=>params[:resume]}
```

I'm getting :  3: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'conditions' needs to be a hash, you have two hashes. Try this:

```
@posts = Post.search(:conditions => {:search => params[:search], :resume => params[:resume]})
```